# Quick Links for Member Groups

Tags: members, member-management, cpanel

I have a couple of Member Groups that have access to the cPanel. I'd like to provide them with an easy way to access special frontend pages (instead of them having to type the URLs). There is a "Quick Links Manager" that I see as Super Admin, but whatever I put there doesn't seem to appear in the other Member Groups; also, I don't want all Member Groups that have cPanel access to access these special pages.

Is there something in EE that I can set so that certain Member Groups will have an easy way to access these pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two add-ons that will allow you to define Quick Links globally per member group in the Control Panel:

1) [**Member Group Tabs**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-group-tabs)

> This extension allows you to create navigation tabs for entire member
>   groups in the ExpressionEngine control panel.

OR

2) [**Zoo Flexible Admin**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin)

> Zoo Flexible Admin lets you fully customize the control panel menu per
>   membergroup. Insert custom links, rename, re-order and remove menu
>   items in order to create a more intuitive menu.

Zoo Flexible Admin is *really* powerful, giving you complete control of the entire CP navigation per member group.